# Improve processing time for array calculation

Tags: c

The code look like this
sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array [j + 2]+ ... array[j + n];
how do I replace the j+n inside the bracket to improve the timing?

Comment: Is this a theoretical EECS class exercise, or a real-world question? Are you measuring timing as 'unoptimized instruction count'? Are we supposed to assume any particular instruction set (MIPS, x86, ?)

Answer (score 7):

You *don't* do this. Unless you have a brain-dead compiler, it should be able to optimise this quite adequately.

If you're going to do this level of micro-optimisation, you need to start looking at the underlying assembly code, *not* assuming that your compiler will blindly translate your code into exactly-equivalent assembly code.

You will also need to understand the intricacies of your target platform better than the people that write your compiler which is frankly, based on the insane code I've seen coming from `gcc` in high optimisation levels, unlikely :-)

You'll usually get a better return on investment if you concentrate on big-picture optimisations like algorithm selection and so forth.

What you *should* do (if you haven't already) is profile the code, once finished, to see where the bottlenecks are (and *only* if it's underperforming: there's no point in optimising something that's already running fast enough).

Then concentrate on those bottlenecks. *Measure, don't guess!*

---

By way of example, I was actually going to show you how well optimised the following code became:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int j, sum, array[50];
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        array[j] = 999 - j * 2;
    j = 22;
    sum = array[j] + array[j+1] + array [j + 2] + array[j + 3];
    return 0;
}
```

but under gcc optimisation level 3, it became:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp         ; prolog
    xorl    %eax, %eax   ; return value
    movl    %esp, %ebp   ; epilog 1
    popl    %ebp         ; epilog 2
    ret
```

Yes, that's right, it's just the stack prolog and epilog code and setting of the return value, with no calculations in sight. `gcc` has (rightly) figured out that none of the calculations are used anywhere so has optimised them totally out of existence.

---

Once you use it, the relevant code becomes a simple:

```
movl    116(%esp), %eax
addl    112(%esp), %eax
addl    120(%esp), %eax
addl    124(%esp), %eax
```

and you'd be hard-pressed getting it much more optimised than that.

Comment: The chalenge is no optimization is allowed

Comment: Wooo, dead code removal. The `j+1...j+n` stuff could (should?) be in a loop too.

Comment: @vincent: Add some context to your question and you won't get useless answers.

Comment: @vincent, if you're not allowed optimisation, then it's probably a homework question and you should have stated so (or at least included that limitation in the question). In the real world, optimisation is allowed. In any case, the crux of my answer stands: examine the assembly output and test different scenarios. You _cannot_ make a blanket assertion that a piece of C code will run faster in all environments.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
T* aj = &(array[j]);
sum = aj[0] + aj[1] + ...
```

?

Comment: This just makes the code look different. It won't affect the timing.

Comment: @Graeme: it really depends on optimizer. Some embedded compilers are not particularly good in optimizations, so this actually **may** bring some performance gain.

Comment: fair enough. I take back my -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *aj

aj = &(array[j]);
```

is correct, and the sum is equal to

```
sum += *aj + *(aj+1) + *(aj+2) ....
```

It defenitly would perform your code if you start whit

```
aj = &(array[0]);
```

and then just make the adds to aj