# how to remove an add that's inside the square brackets in a for statement

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, loops

I have this code in C:

```
for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Do not alter anything above this line

    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-7; j=j+8) {
        sum += array[j]+array[j+1]+array[j+2]+array[j+3]+array[j+4]+array[j+5]+array[j+6]+array[j+7];
    }
    for(;j<ARRAY_SIZE;j++)
            sum+= array[j];

    // Do not alter anything below this line.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    if (sum != checksum) {
        printf("Checksum error!\n");
    }
    sum = 0;

}
```

Where ARRAY_SIZE=9973 and N_TIMES=200000

This excersice is for optimization. How can I remove that add that's inside the square brackets in the inner loop (ex. array[j+4]) ?? Please help me.

Comment: You say the code is "C" but you've tagged the question as "C++". Those are two different languages, and solutions can differ greatly. Which language is it?

Comment: You can just set an appropriately typed pointer `p = array[j]` then start indexing ala p[0], p[1] (equivalent to array[j], array[j + 1]).  By all means experiment and measure, but don't expect this to speed anything up.  Even your manual loop unrolling is a technique from 20 years ago that a modern compiler will do for you anyway.

Comment: The best way to sum an array of numbers is to use vector instruction sets like SSE2. Removing the adds is not going to improve performance; the compiler would probably optimize an inner loop to the same thing anyway.

Comment: Interesting.  This must be a homework assignment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262285/improve-processing-time-for-array-calculation

Answer (score 1):

Here's the results for some testing I did. I tried 3 versions of your code, one with no unrolling, one with your unrolling and one using sse extensions. Since you didn't state the type of your array I've used integers, in the sequence 1..ARRAY_SIZE.

Firstly the set up stuff, emmintrin.h is the header for sse intrinsics.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emmintrin.h> // SSE2
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 9973;
    const size_t N_TIMES = 200000;
    int * array = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(*array));
    for (size_t i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;++i) array[i] = i;
    clock_t start, stop;
```

Next a simple loop. If the optimiser's smart this should be as fast as anything else, the compiler knows that you're adding together adjacent array elements and can unroll, use sse etc. as needed.

```
    // Using normal loop
    start = clock();
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i=0;i<N_TIMES;++i){
        for (size_t j=0;j<ARRAY_SIZE;++j){
            sum += array[j];
        }   
    }
    stop = clock();
    printf("normal %d\t%e\n",sum,difftime(stop,start));
```

Next for comparison your loop

```
    // Using unwrapped loop
    start = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (size_t i=0;i<N_TIMES;++i){
        size_t j=0;
        for (;j<ARRAY_SIZE-7;j+=8){
            sum += array[j+0] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] +
                array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] + 
                array[j+6] + array[j+7];
        }
        for (;j<ARRAY_SIZE;++j){
            sum += array[j];
        }   
    }
    stop = clock();
    printf("unrolled %d\t%e\n",sum,difftime(stop,start));
```

And finally a loop using sse. The type __m128i designates a 128 bit integer array, which has to be operated on using the _mm intrinsics. This code loads the array 4 integers at a time into a register, adds that to a summation register and then unpacks the summation register at the end.

```
    // Using sse
    start = clock();
    sum = 0;
    __m128i sse_sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for (size_t i=0;i<N_TIMES;++i){
        size_t j=0;
        for (;j<ARRAY_SIZE-3;j+=4){
            __m128i slice = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(array+j));
            sse_sum = _mm_add_epi32(sse_sum,slice);
        }
        for (;j<ARRAY_SIZE;++j){
            sum += array[j];
        }   
    }
    int sse_result[4];
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)sse_result,sse_sum);
    for (int i=0;i<4;++i)
        sum += sse_result[i];
    stop = clock();
    printf("sse %d\t%e\n",sum,difftime(stop,start));
}
```

Here are the results for a couple compilers I had available, all targeting 64 bit OSX 10.6. First column is the loop version, then the sum, then the time taken:

```
 $ gcc --version
 i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
 $ gcc loop.c -o loop -msse2 -O3 -std=c99 -ftree-vectorize && ./loop
 normal   -2068657536   7.525430e+05
 unrolled -2068657536   9.638840e+05
 sse      -2068657536   4.929820e+05

$ gcc-4.5 --version
gcc-4.5 (GCC) 4.5.0
$ gcc-4.5 loop.c -o loop -msse2 -O3 -std=c99 -ftree-vectorize && ./loop
normal   -2068657536    9.721320e+05
unrolled -2068657536    9.610700e+05
sse      -2068657536    1.196051e+06

$ clang --version
clang version 2.0 (trunk 103456)
$ clang loop.c -o loop -msse2 -O3 -std=c99 -ftree-vectorize && ./loop
normal   -2068657536    1.155552e+06
unrolled -2068657536    9.613550e+05
sse      -2068657536    1.195248e+06
```

As you can see the results vary wildly across compilers. In gcc it looks like the normal loop is well optimised, performing better than the unrolled loop and nearly as good as sse in the Apple compiler, while for baseline gcc  the sse version lags behind quite a bit (probably because Apple have set up better default optimisations for their compiler). Clang doesn't optimise so well, although my version is a bit old, and the unrolled loop is best for this case.

In my opinion the best way to go would be to use the basic loop, provided that your compiler does automatic vectorization (that's what the -ftree-vectorize is for), as that's the easiest to understand. You're going to get more out of fiddling around with the compiler optimisation levels than manually unrolling loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner loop:

```
for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-7; j=j+8) {
    for (int k = j; k < (k + 8); ++k) {
        sum += array[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that N_TIMES=200000 and ARRAY_SIZE=9973

Comment: What would be the point of first unwinding the loop (which was the purpose of the original code) and then changing it back to an inner loop? Might just as well have one loop that sums all the elements.

Comment: is just an exercise for optimization, I know that it could be done in just 1 loop but that is exactly the problem, I have to figure out how to remove that add from the loop to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner loop. It won't add complexity to the algorithm, since the inner loop will range from 0 to 7, always. If this is really C, you can't create another variable. So you can do this:

```
for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-7; j=j+8) {
    sum += array[j];
    for (array[j] = 0; array[j] < 8; array[j]++) {
        sum += array[array[j]];
    }
}
```

I guess it will work, since you won't need `array[j]` anymore.

Comment: The problem is that N_TIMES=200000 and ARRAY_SIZE=9973 so I think it wont make it faster... My best time in the linux server was 7.2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: This answer is not valid now as earlier it was tagged as C++

Try [std::accumulate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) for C++

Here's an example

```
#include <numeric>

int main(){
   int buf[10] = {7, 8, 1, 9, 5, 0, 2, 3, 6, 4};

   int sum = std::accumulate (buf, buf+7, 0);
}
```

Comment: @James: It's implemented in the STL and does the summation by running the same loop that you and I would run if we implemented it ourselves

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an attempt of loop unrolling. Try this instead.

```
for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-7;) {
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
    sum += array[j++];
}
for(;j<ARRAY_SIZE;j++)
        sum+= array[j];
```